# MiniTest for Post in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, minitest

Comments_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class CommentsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should create a comment" do

    assert_difference('Comment.count') do
      post :create, comment: {user_id: 1, job_id: 1, content: "This is a comment"}
    end

  end
end
```

Comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
        render :json => {:status => 'success', :entry => @comment}
    else
        render :json => {:status => 'error'}
    end
end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:job_id, :user_id, :content)
  end
end
```

Comments table:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :user_id
      t.string :job_id
      t.string :content

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Finished in 0.162164s, 110.9987 runs/s, 117.1653 assertions/s.

1) Failure:
CommentsControllerTest#test_should_create_a_comment       

"Comment.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 4
Actual: 3
```

Any ideas why this isn't being created? Creating a comment works on the actual application, but for some reason it isn't passing in the test

Note: I have 3 comments created in the fixture (that's how it's getting a count of 3).

Comment: Perfect! You're right. It said I was being redirected because I wasn't logged in. I had to put this in my comment_controller_test.rb file: setup do controller.class.skip_before_filter :require_login end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug response from the server.
Add `puts response.body` after `post :create, comment: { ... }` and check logs.